# How can I acces a route parameter two parents up in Angular 11?

Tags: html, css, json, angular, typescript

I would like to know how to access lever two parent routes in angular. For example: How do i get the **componentId** in **AttributeListComponent** if i use following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/components', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'components', component: SideNavComponent,
    children: [
      {path: ':componentId', component: ComponentTabComponent, children: [
          {path: '', redirectTo: 'entities', pathMatch: 'full'},
          {path: 'entities', component: EntityListComponent, children: [
              {path: ':entityId', component: EntityTabComponent,
                children: [
                  {path: '', redirectTo: 'attributes', pathMatch: 'full'},
                  {path: 'attributes', component: AttributeListComponent},
                  {path: 'tasks', component: TaskListComponent}
                ]}
            ]},
          {path: 'domains', component: DomainListComponent}
        ]},
    ]},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: Show an example of how/why you wold use this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse router tree up with `parent` property. Example:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ...
  this.route.parent.parent.parent.queryParams.subscribe(...
```

Calculate how many `parent`'s you need yourself :). That is based on how many `children` you have in routes file.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find that.